# XML Parser in PHP not parsing

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to parse the following xml https://ota.cartrawler.com/cartrawlerota/files/static/ctlocation.EN.xml

I have the following code

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("ctlocation.EN.xml") 

       or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $loc){
    foreach($loc->children() as $loca => $data){
      echo $data->location['name'];
      echo "<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

It's not giving any error but it's not parsing any info, any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("ctlocation.EN.xml") 
       or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->Country as $loc){
  $name = $loc[0]['name'];
  echo $name;
  echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: How can I parse locations?